# Finding number of zeros of $f(z) = z^{2019} + 8z + 7$ inside the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the number of zeros of $f(z) = z^{2019} + 8z + 7$ inside the unit disk. I've tried to apply Rouche's Theorem, but no combination of terms seems to work. Also, the Argument Principle seems to fail because when I was computing the winding number of $f(\gamma)$ around the origin, I realized $f$ has a zero on the unit disk. Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can apply the [symmetric version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Symmetric_version) of Rouché's theorem to
$$
\begin{align}
 f(z) &= z^{2019} + 8z + 7 \, ,\\
 g(z) &= 8z + 7 \, .
\end{align}
$$
On the boundary of the unit disk we have
$$
\begin{align}
|f(z) | &\ge |8 z| - 7 - |z^{2019}| = 0 \, ,\\
|g(z) | &\ge |8 z| - 7 = 1\, .
\end{align}
$$
Equality holds in the second inequality only for $z = 1$, but at that point the first inequality is strict.

It follows that equality cannot hold simultaneously in both inequalities, i.e.
$$
|f(z) | + |g(z) | > 1 = |z^{2019}| = |f(z) - g(z)|
$$
on the boundary of the unit disk. Rouché's theorem then states that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros inside the unit disk (which is one).

Comment: This was exactly the kind of solution I was hoping for! Thank you.