# $|f(z) - g(z)| < |f(z)|$ vs $|f(z) - g(z)| < |g(z)|$ in Rouche's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value, rouches-theorem

I was reading Marsden's Basic Complex Analysis and noticed that Rouche's Theorem was formulated as requiring $|f(z) - g(z)| < |f(z)|$ (for all $z$ on closed $\gamma$, etc.), and the statement was that $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ have the same amount of zeros and poles (for simple $\gamma$).

However, I've previously seen the requirement presented as $|f(z) - g(z)| < |g(z)|$ (with the same statement) - and indeed it seems like Marsden uses this version of the theorem in Example 6.2.12 without any justification. So, my question is: how are these two formulations equivalent? Am I missing some simple triangle inequality manipulation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply exchange the roles of $f$ and $g$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the difference? Assume that the first formulation holds. Now if you have $|f(z)-g(z)|<|g(z)|$, then$$|g(z)-f(z)|=|f(z)-g(z)|<|g(z)|,$$and therefore $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros.

Answer (score 3):

Those statements are equivalent, it is just a matter of exchanging the roles of $f$ and $g$.

There is also a [“symmetric” version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Symmetric_version) of Rouché's theorem: It suffices to require that
$$
 |f(z) - g(z)| < |f(z)| + |g(z)|
$$
on the boundary of the domain.

Comment: Here is an example where the “symmetric” version of Rouchés theorem turned out to be more useful that the “standard” version: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3475397/42969.